# eBay API call not working for EBAY-ES (Spain) Global ID

Tags: ebay-api

I am trying to fetch a book details from www.ebay.es by **EAN** number. But its always showing **"Invalid product ID value."**. (My-App-ID needs to be changed)

http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByProduct&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-ES&SECURITY-APPNAME=My-APP-ID&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&REST-PAYLOAD&productId.@type=ISBN&productId=9781408880715

But I can search the same EAN from spanish site of ebay. It means the EAN number is Valid. Here is the link -

http://www.ebay.es/itm/Fantastic-Beasts-y-donde-to-Find-Les-de-J-K-Rowling-/361919661849?hash=item544417c719:g:jpEAAOSwSlBYuUzL

And I can fetch the data from UK site easily by changing the Global-ID. Here is the link (My-App-ID needs to be changed)-

http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByProduct&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-GB&SECURITY-APPNAME=My-APP-ID&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&REST-PAYLOAD&productId.@type=ISBN&productId=9781408880715

Where I am doing Wrong? Please advise. Thanks in advance.